# angular2: how can I monitor for ajaxError like I did with jQuery before?

Tags: jquery, ajax, angular

Back with just jQuery, I would listen for any ajaxError events simply with:

```
$(document).on('ajaxError', someFunction);
```

But now with Angular2, I don't know how or where to put something like this (I was using it to make sure the user was still logged in)?

Is there a hook to all the services that may fail?  Do I do it the same?  Where would I put something like this?  Very new to Angular2, any direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular2 you're using Http service to do all your Ajax calls.

So if we find a way to intercept it, we can log all the possible error s:

So one way is to wrap the Http base class :

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}


  get(url) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    return this.http.get(url, {
      headers: headers
    }).catch( this.handleError );
  }


 private handleError ( error : any ) {
      consoe.log('do something with the error ');
     return Observable.throw( errMsg );
  }
}
```

And then obviously , instead of Http, you should use HttpService